# render element after click in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components

I am trying to render an element on the page after a user clicks the button, but once clicked nothing happens.  Trying to find out what I'm doing wrong.

```
class Foo extends React.Component{
  render(){

    const showThingy = () => {
      return (
        <div>This is not showing when clicked</div>
      );
    }

    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={showThingy}>
      </div>
    )
   }
  }
```

Comment: use a state variable (boolean value), and render the div using that boolean value.